# "Absurd Length" error in Automator Run Shell Script

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

So, I have this camera system which automatically uploads Videos to an FTP server when it detects motion.

Those files, I want to move to another FTP server automatically, (my Home Assistant server), which then pings my phone with a notification.

To Download and Upload between the two FTP servers, I'm using a tool called **FavoriteFTP** for Mac OS X. It allows me to set up profiles which you can run through a command line.

I then sat up 2 "Apps" through Automator to launch the different Profiles in Favorite FTP. One for Downloading all files from the remote FTP server and one for Uploading those files to another FTP (My Home Assistant Server).

Last but not least, I made a third Automator App, to transcode the files from AVI to MP4 using HandbrakeCLI.

So here are the 3 Automator Apps:

This is the ftpdownload app:

```
/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile "Download from FTP"
```

This is the ftptranscode app:

```
SRC="/Users/frederik/cctv/motion"
DEST="/Users/frederik/cctv/motion"
DEST_EXT=mp4
HANDBRAKE_CLI=HandBrakeCLI

for FILE in "$SRC"/.avi
do
    filename=$(basename "$FILE")
    extension=${filename##.}
    filename=${filename%.}
    /usr/local/bin/HandBrakeCLI -i "$FILE" -o "$DEST"/"$filename".$DEST_EXT
done
find /Users/frederik/cctv/motion -name '.avi' -exec rm -r     {} ;
```

And this is the ftpsync app (upload to second FTP):

```
/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile "Upload CH1 to HASS
```

What my AppleScript then does, is running these 3 Apps in an infinite loop

```
on idle
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "ftpdownload"
        run
        delay 10
    end tell
    tell application "ftptranscode"
        run
        delay 20
    end tell
    tell application "ftpsyncapp"
        run
    end tell
    tell application "ftpsyncappCH2"
        run
    end tell
    return 10
end tell
end idle
```

So to summarize:
**ftpdownload** is the app which downloads all AVI files from the remote FTP server
**ftptranscode** is the app which converts those files into MP4
**ftpsyncapp** is the app which then uploads those files to the second FTP server
and **ftpsyncappCH2** does the same, but only with files with the word "CH2" in the filenames

**Here's the problem**
After a day or two, I get an error from one of the Automator Scripts (see image below). However I just get a single Window Popup. So Im thinking it's just one of the 3 automator Apps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoS9Q.png

It seems that there's a limit on how many times I can loop this
(I just need this running forever)

So right now, I have to click "OK" every day, which is a bit annoying.

**How do I avoid getting this error message once a day, so my scripts can run in a loop forever?**

Comment: There's really not enough information here to address this issue. I mean, I can see potential problems, but you seem to be using an app you've made to call a bunch of other apps you've made, and set up all sorts of weird race conditions and data exchanges. I assume each of the four apps in your first png are single-line shell script calls as shown in your last png. If you could post the contents of those (in text please, not images) I can show you how to combine them into a single app.

Comment: Hey @TedWrigley! Thank you for the reply!
I have updated the original post with much more info. Let me know if this is sufficient!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer two suggestions.

First: Instead of using automator, create a stay-open script application that uses the `do shell script` function of AppleScript to do the work. The idle handler for that would look something like this:

```
on idle
    do shell script "/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Download from FTP'"
    
    do shell script "
        SRC='/Users/frederik/cctv/motion'
        DEST='/Users/frederik/cctv/motion'
        DEST_EXT=mp4
        HANDBRAKE_CLI=HandBrakeCLI

        for FILE in \"$SRC\"/.avi
        do
            filename=$(basename \"$FILE\")
            extension=${filename##.}
            filename=${filename%.}
            /usr/local/bin/HandBrakeCLI -i \"$FILE\" -o \"$DEST\"/\"$filename\".$DEST_EXT
        done
        find /Users/frederik/cctv/motion -name '.avi' -exec rm -r {} ;"
    
    do shell script "/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Upload CH1 to HASS'"
    
    do shell script "/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Upload CH2 to HASS'"
    
    -- check every 30 seconds
    return 30
end idle
```

Note that `do shell script` will in most cases wait for a response from the called script before advancing to the next applescript command, so the `delay` commands wouldn't be necessary. If the Favorite FTP is running its commands on detached background threads that might cause issues, but that seems unlikely.

Also, I used a 30 second idle period because I didn't want to re-invoke the FavoriteFTP app too often.  By default, script apps have a one second idle interval; returning 30 makes that a 30 second interval, which ought to be enough for the app to finish its last cycle.

---

Second, since this is really just a set of shell scripts, and you're only using AppleScript as a container to run them  periodically, you could just write the whole thing as a single shell script:

```
/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Download from FTP'
SRC='/Users/frederik/cctv/motion'
DEST='/Users/frederik/cctv/motion'
DEST_EXT=mp4
HANDBRAKE_CLI=HandBrakeCLI

for FILE in \"$SRC\"/.avi
do
    filename=$(basename \"$FILE\")
    extension=${filename##.}
    filename=${filename%.}
    /usr/local/bin/HandBrakeCLI -i \"$FILE\" -o \"$DEST\"/\"$filename\".$DEST_EXT
done
find /Users/frederik/cctv/motion -name '.avi' -exec rm -r {} ;
/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Upload CH1 to HASS'
/Applications/FavoriteFTP.app/Contents/MacOS/FavoriteFTPPro -profile 'Upload CH2 to HASS'
```

save it to disk, and run it on schedule as a launchd job. Launchd is designed to do that. You'll write a plist file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>user.ftp.transfer.mdvideos</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/shellscript</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

save it at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/user.ftp.transfer.mdvideos.plist`, then load it as a job using the unix command

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/user.ftp.transfer.mdvideos.plist`
```

See `man launchctl` and `man launchd.plist` for details